# nGinx keeps shutting down

Tags: linux, nginx, ubuntu

The nginx process keeps shutting itself off, here are the errors

```
2023/04/18 11:47:29 [alert] 11073#0: worker process 11312 exited on signal 9
2023/04/18 11:47:29 [alert] 11073#0: fork() failed while spawning "worker process" (12: Cannot allocate memory)
2023/04/18 11:47:29 [alert] 11073#0: could not respawn worker process
```

I know it has enough ram, it's a VPS I control and I've jacked its ram up to 4GB and still same thing. It's a very lightweight nginx server, no PHP, simple image serving. Running nginx 1.0.15, I know it's old, but it worked for many years no issues. Nothing's changed on this VPS in years.

Comment: Too much gin, too less tonic? :-D What is the count of the worker process? Maybe it's a RAM hardware issue?

Comment: Perhaps providing more information, such as `nginx.conf`, would help in getting a useful answer. Also consider explaining why you cannot upgrade to a more recent version of nginx, especially considering that they have been very good at supporting older `nginx.conf` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

`fork() failed while spawning "worker process" (12: Cannot allocate memory)`
Is the clue.

If you look at `man 2 fork` you can  find out what conditions lead to that position.

> `ENOMEM fork()` failed to allocate the necessary kernel structures because memory is tight.
>
> `ENOMEM` An attempt was made to create a child process in a PID namespace whose "init" process has terminated.  See pid_namespaces(7).

Its should be one of these two conditions. Does the entire VPS around the same time get restarted? If so there is your answer.

You can potentially test this if you cant tell by doing `ps -o lstart 1` in the container and checking when the `init` process was started.

Else, if you still get this when it says 'memory is tight' it might be because overall system memory is tight. Thats not something you may be privvy to in your container, so you'd need to request more information from the hosting provider.

Comment: As my initial post stated, I have upped the VPS ram to 4GB and tried again, still same issue. So it's not available ram. The host name I control, host node has over 48GB of free ram still available unallocated. And checking uptime after this happens, no, the VPS has not rebooted in about 3 months time.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message you provided, it seems that the worker process is exiting due to a `signal 9`, which indicates a `SIGKILL` signal. Additionally, the error message suggests that the `fork() system call is failing`, which means that the process is unable to create a new child process.

The error message "Cannot allocate memory" suggests that the system may be running out of memory, which could be causing the fork() system call to fail. One possible solution to this issue is to increase the amount of memory available to the system.

You can try to check the available memory on your server using the "free -tm" command, which will display information about the available memory and swap space. If the system is running low on memory, you may need to add more memory to your server or adjust your nginx configuration to use less memory.

Another possible solution is to reduce the number of worker processes in your nginx configuration. You can do this by adjusting the "worker_processes" setting in your nginx.conf file. By reducing the number of worker processes, you can decrease the memory usage of your nginx server.

Comment: As my initial post stated, I have upped the VPS ram to 4GB and tried again, still same issue. So it's not available ram. The host name I control, host node has over 48GB of free ram still available unallocated. And checking uptime after this happens, no, the VPS has not rebooted in about 3 months time.

Comment: Worker processes was set to 1 already

Comment: @jfreak53 please share your nginx config file.

Answer (score 0):

Add [swap](https://portal.perforce.com/s/article/2991).
Also, make sure the're isn't any credentials/privileges problem.

Also, reffering to [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40883/nginx-out-of-memory-kill-process) question where some app was limited with the RAM it could use. What does these workers do? This might be your answer.

Also, have you tried to [update](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/3314#issuecomment-627357268) everything?